# how to exclude results in loopback based on related models

Tags: loopbackjs

I am using mongo connector.

I have a `offers` model which has a `hasMany` relation with my `Users` model via `interested_users` key. Basically the idea is that an user can mark an offer as `interested` or `not_interested`, and I need to exclude the `not_interested` offers. What is the best/efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: exclude `not_interested` from what ?

Comment: @Overdrivr exclude them from being fetched when running a `find` operation on `Users` model for listing all available offers, which should include all offers in the offers collection except those which has been marked as `not_interested` in the linked `interested_users` model.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I fully understand your issue, but it is definitely related to [querying data with loopback REST API](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-Using"stringified"JSONinRESTqueries), and especially [`where` filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Where+filter#Wherefilter-Defaultscopeswithwherefilters)

If your model offer has a property `someone_is_interested` (boolean), then the following request could work for you

```
GET /api/offers/?filter[where][someone_is_interested]=true
```

But I have the feeling you want to use the relation to store all users that are interested in an offer. In this case, simply establish the relation between any interested user and the offer with this request (in the database, one instance of offer with id=1, and a user with id=2:

```
PUT /api/offers/1/interested_users/rel/2
```

And to remove the relation (just the relation, not the user or offer)

```
DELETE /api/offers/1/interested_users/rel/2
```

Then, you can simply query all related users of offer with id=1, which will give you all interested users on that offer

```
GET /api/offers/1/interested_users
```